# MediaWiki: How to uncheck creating redirects on move by default?

Tags: redirect, checkbox, mediawiki

If I allow users to move pages, the checkbox "Create a redirect" is checked by default. What can I do for this check box to be unchecked by default? Is there some kind of configuration option I can set?

Comment: There isn't any.

Comment: That's sad. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If you are desperte you can hack something together in Javascript or change the WebRequest object in a hook, wouldn't recommend it though. If you have a robust use case for it you could file a [bug request](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/), it would be a trivial change.

Comment: You're right. I'll file an issue for that. I did that already for something, I don't know  how, when and even if they are considered.

Comment: It's an open-source project so it depends on whether there are people interested in that specific area of the code, how much free time they have etc. It's always worth a try.